# Python: Compare Lists

Tags: python

I have two lists `a` and `b`:

```
a = ['146769015', '163081689', '172235774', ...]
b = [['StackOverflow (146769015)'], ['StackOverflow (146769015)'], ['StackOverflow (163081689)'], ...]
```

What I'm trying to do is to check if the elements of list `a` are in list `b`, and if they are, how many times they appear.

In this case the output should be:

```
'146769015':2
'163081689':1
```

I've already tried the `set()` function but that does not seem to work

```
print(set(a)&set(b))
```

And i get this

```
    print(set(a)&set(b))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is it possible to do what i want?

Thank you all.

Comment: So what did you actually try?

Comment: Remember, this is a site to help you fix programming problems, not write your code for you.

Comment: Please post your work so that we can help you figure it out.

Comment: The answer to the question you actually posted is "yes". The answer to the implied question of "will someone do it for me?" is "no".

Comment: I think there is no build in function that does that. Why not write a custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform set(a) & set(b), you're trying to see which elements both lists share. There are a couple errors in your logic.

- First, your first list is comprised of strings. Your second list is comprised of lists.
- Second, the elements of your second list are never the same than your first list, because the first has only numbers, and the second has numbers and letters.
- Third, even if you only extract the numbers, the intersection of both sets will bring which numbers are on both sets, but not how many times.

A good approach might be to extract the numbers in your second list and then count occurrences if they are present in list `a`:

```
from collections import Counter
import re
a=['146769015', '163081689', '172235774']
b=[['StackOverflow (146769015)'],['StackOverflow (146769015)'],['StackOverflow (163081689)']]

numbs = [re.search('\d+', elem[0]).group(0) for elem in b]
cnt = Counter()
for n in numbs:
    if n in a:
        cnt[n]+= 1
```

### Output:

```
Counter({'146769015': 2, '163081689': 1})
```

I'll leave as homework to you to research what are dictionaries and Counters.

Comment: I already had used the Counters to count the number of times the same string appears in list a, and worked fine.
Thank you for ur approach

Comment: You could also convert `a` to a `set` to speed this up.

Comment: Can u explain me this codeline:`numbs = [re.search('\d+', elem[0]).group(0) for elem in b]`? I know that u are using regex to find any decimal digit, but is that so?

Comment: Almost exactly that: it's a regex that looks for one or more consecutive digits in the strings, and then extracts the first occurrence of that (thus `group(0)`)

Comment: When i run ur code, i get this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
numbs= [re.search('\d+', elem[0]).group(0) for elem in b]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It seems there are some empty lists in `b`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Joao/PycharmProjects/ProjetoFinal/WinRule.py", line 26, in <module>
    numbs = [re.search('\d+', elem[0]).group(0) for elem in b]
  File "C:/Users/Joao/PycharmProjects/ProjetoFinal/WinRule.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    numbs= [re.search('\d+', elem[0]).group(0) for elem in b]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Yes i have some empty lists, because i'm quering from neo4j, and i get some empty results according to the database i'm using

Comment: you could do something like `b = [i for i in b if i != []]` to remove empty lists

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky when you have a string as a subset of strings, otherwise I think you could use a Counter from collections and iterate that using a as a key.

Otherwise you can flatten the list and nested loop through it.

```
from collections import defaultdict
flat_list = [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
c = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for string in a:
    for string2 in flat_list:
        if string in string2:
            c[string] += 1
```

Comment: Why do you use `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` instead of `defaultdict(int)`?

Comment: What's the meaning of `lambda:0`?

Comment: @wjandrea Honestly because I didn't know defaultdict(int) defaulted to 0!

Comment: @أنيسيتوروي lambda: 0 is the default behaviour for the value when creating a key in the defaultdict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary:

```
a=['146769015', '163081689', '172235774']
b=[['StackOverflow (146769015)'],['StackOverflow (146769015)'],['StackOverflow (163081689)']]

c = {}
for s in a:
    for d in b:
        for i in d:
            if s in i:
                if s not in c:
                    c[s] = 1
                else:
                    c[s] += 1
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'146769015': 2, '163081689': 1}
```